# React Route Dom v6.4 - network path - as localhost is working fine

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Citizen dev attempting this.
I have everything working fine with "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0" in localhost...
But when I npm run build and deploy the build contents to a server http://sww.acme.com
in the directory /tas/travel-events/
So it's now http://blah.acme.com/tas/travel-events/

Every time I go to the root it renders the error page.

```
path: "/",
element: <Layout />,
errorElement: <Error />,
```

I'm following the syntax of the tutorial.https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial
There are no network errors delivering the content.

[image]

What's a little strange is that in a previous attempt before attempting the tutorial method, I tried a different way and it seemed to work, so if the answer is in the basename how do I insert that into the syntax below...

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter basename={"/tas/sas-travel-events"}>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here's the contents of the travel-events network directory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [basename](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename) property is passed when configuring the router.

See [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) [type declaration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#type-declaration)

> ```
> function createBrowserRouter(
>   routes: RouteObject[],
>   opts?: {
>     basename?: string;
>     window?: Window;
>   }
> ): RemixRouter;
> ```

Example:

```js
function createBrowserRouter(
  routes: RouteObject[],
  opts?: {
    basename?: string;
    future?: FutureConfig;
    hydrationData?: HydrationState;
    window?: Window;
  }
): RemixRouter;
```

Comment: thanks Drew, that makes sense... ... so with homepage set to...
 "homepage": "./",
and the basename in the const router = createBrowserRouter(opts) it results in a blank page on the server and on localhost. 
I remove the basename in the const router = createBrowserRouter(opts) and localhost works but the server is still blank.
any thoughts here?

Comment: @RichardC I think you typically will want to leave the `"homepage": "."` in your package.json file unless you have specific need to change it accordingly for the server environment you are deploying your app to. See the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs for more details. There may be a section there that matches your server environment.